# Accessing another model from an .each loop in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a restaurant manager app that has users, orders, and meals. User has many orders, order has many meals. I want a table that lists all orders by a user together with meals' names and prices. I have three models: `User`, `Order`, and `Meal`. While it's not a problem to access `order_id` from this loop:

```
- @userOrders.each do |order|
    %tr
      %td= order.id
```

when I try to access meal's name by

```
- @userOrders.each do |order|
    %tr
      %td= order.id
      %td= order.meals.name
```

here's what I get:

[Table with what's supposes to be meals' names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hI21H.png)

In Ruby console, when I type `user.orders[1].meals`, I get:

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XA8Sv.png)

This is my `orders_controller.rb`

```
  def index
    user_id = current_user.id
    @userOrders = Order.where(:user_id => user_id)    
  end
```

Below is my `order.rb`:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :meals
end
```

`user.rb`:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :orders
end
```

and `meal.rb`:

```
class Meal < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
end
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: My expected output is to list all meals associated with certain order_id in one <td> element.

Answer (score 4):

Order has many meals. Many meals can't have just one name for them all. That's what you're trying to do with `order.meals.name`. Each meal has its own name. Iterate meals too. Something like this:

```
- orders.each do |order|
  - order.meals.each do |meal|
    = meal.name
```

Comment: In addition, you should include the `meals` when fetching the `orders` to avoid _N + 1 queries_, see [Eager Loading Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)